# Different page appear when testing

Tags: testing

What I want to do is checking whether a link is exist on frontpage.

I've set up a content with with node id 5 as my frontpage.

But when testing it, and see the verbose message (http://screencast.com/t/ldWSBwJNcO)
different page appear. The default drupal frontpage appear instead of the content that I've set up.

My test code:

```
class MyUserManagementTestCase extends DrupalWebTestCase {

  // Some says this improve tests performance
  protected $profile = 'test';

  public static function getInfo() {
    return array(
      'name' => 'My User Management Test Case',
      'description' => 'Ensure that the My functionality for user management works.',
      'group' => 'My',
    );
  }

  public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
  }

  public function testFrontpage() {
    $this->drupalGet('');
    $this->assertResponse(200, t('Frontpage page is accessible'));
    $this->assertLinkByHref('user/register');
    $this->assertLinkByHref('user/login');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Simpletest each time the test is run. New Drupal install will occur. You are testing the Simpletest Database right now. There is a possibility to run simpletest on "live" db. To do so add `$this->originalPrefix = $GLOBALS['db_prefix']` to your `setUp()`